# Does not work as before Verilog initial construction in ModelSim Altera Edition 10.4

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, modelsim, intel-fpga, quartus

Since version 10.4, start problem with initial block. Like this:

```
reg [31:0] init_ram[15:0];

initial begin
   init_ram[0] = 32'h1234_5678;
   init_ram[1] = 32'h8765_4321;
   ...
end

always_ff @(posedge clk)
   init_ram[addr] <= data;
```

Or

```
module test(
   input clk,
   ...
   output reg a
);

initial a = 1'b1;

always @(posedge clk)
   a <= ...;
```

ModelSim 10.4 error:

> Error (suppressible): (vlog-7061) {path} Variable 'init_ram' driven in
>   an always_ff block, may not be driven by any other process

In older versions all works well.

You don't know which `ModelSim` parameter should I change to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

One of the problems with the `always_ff` and `always_comb` constructs is that they are supposed to check the synthesizability during simulation, except that there is no standard for what is synthesizable. If the intent is that the `initial` blocks are just for simulation, then you will need to change the `always_ff` to `always` or change the `initial` block to use `force/release` instead.

Answer (score 0):

One idea for a work around to your problem is to add a `reset`
signal and use it to initialize the value of a register.

Well, probably this
would be a good way to give an initial value to your flip-flops.

This should be something like:

```
reg [31:0] init_ram[15:0];
input reset;

always_ff @(posedge clk) begin
   if (reset) begin
      init_ram[0] <= 32'h1234_5678;
      init_ram[1] <= 32'h8765_4321;
   end
   else begin
      init_ram[addr] <= data;
```

Or this:

```
module test(
   input clk,
   input reset,
   ...
   output reg a
);

always @(posedge clk) begin
   if (reset) begin
      a <= 1'b1;
   end
   else begin
      a <= ...;
```

Comment: Use the reset for memory block it's not good idea. RAM does not support reset.

Comment: For output signal i can use only asynchronous reset for correct power-up state without clock. ModelSim support - output reg a = 1'b1 - but Quartus synthesis ignore it